# Creating a mirrored, grouped barplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, multiple-axes, grouped-bar-chart

I have attempted adapting from some other solutions for slightly different situations. I am not being able to sort this out.

I would like to build a mirrored barplot comparing chemicals with controls, but with results grouped by chemical concentrations, and (if possible) both positive axes.

I provide data below, and an example of I would like it to generally look like.

```
volatiles<-c("hexenal3", "trans2hexenal", "trans2hexenol", "ethyl2hexanol", "phenethylalcohol", "methylsalicylate", "geraniol", "eugenol")


require(reshape2)
dat<-list(
conc1=data.frame("volatile"=volatiles, "focal"=c(26,27,28,28,31,31,30,28), "control"=c(24,31,30,29,24,23,21,25)),
conc2=data.frame("volatile"=volatiles, "focal"=c(29,18,34,17,30,32,35,27), "control"=c(21,42,20,40,25,16,17,29)),
conc3=data.frame("volatile"=volatiles, "focal"=c(33, 5,38, 7,37,35,40,26), "control"=c(18,51,14, 50,15,12,13,31))
)
long.dat<-melt(dat)
```

Attempting the following isn't working. Perhaps I should input a different data structure?

```
ggplot(long.dat, aes(x=L1, group=volatile, y=value, fill=variable)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", position= "identity")
```

I would like it to look similar to this, but with the bars grouped in the triads of different concentrations (and, if possible, with all positive values).

[image: data plot from another software]
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can control the `labels=` on the axis, I'd imagine that you could use `abs(.)` in the labelling function to show the negative numbers as positives (even though the values themselves would need to be negative to be on the left side of the axis).

Comment: fyi, `object 'volatiles' not found`.

Comment: I have edited the code to include an object I'd forgotten, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```r
long.dat$value[long.dat$variable == "focal"] <-  -long.dat$value[long.dat$variable == "focal"]

library(ggplot2)
gg <- ggplot(long.dat, aes(interaction(volatile, L1), value)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), color = "black", stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = abs) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(control = "#00000000", focal = "blue")) +
  coord_flip()
gg
```

[image: ggplot2 bar plot, grouped and filled by 'variable', and 'focal' data to the left and 'control' data to the right of center]

I suspect that the order on the left axis (originally `x`, but flipped to the left with `coord_flip`) will be relevant to you. If the current isn't what you need and using `interaction(L1, volatile)` instead does not give you the correct order, then you will need to combine them intelligently *before* `ggplot(..)`, convert to a `factor`, and control the `levels=` so that they are in the order (and string-formatting) you need.

Most other aspects can be controlled via `+ theme(...)`, such as `legend.position="top"`. I don't know what the asterisks in your demo image might be, but they can likely be added with `geom_point` (making sure to negate those that should be on the left).

For instance, if you have a `$star` variable that indicates there should be a star on each particular row,

```r
set.seed(42)
long.dat$star <- sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), prob=c(0.2,0.8), size=nrow(long.dat), replace=TRUE)
head(long.dat)
#           volatile variable value    L1  star
# 1         hexenal3    focal   -26 conc1  TRUE
# 2    trans2hexenal    focal   -27 conc1  TRUE
# 3    trans2hexenol    focal   -28 conc1 FALSE
# 4    ethyl2hexanol    focal   -28 conc1  TRUE
# 5 phenethylalcohol    focal   -31 conc1 FALSE
# 6 methylsalicylate    focal   -31 conc1 FALSE
```

then you can add it with a single `geom_point` call (and adding the legend move):

```r
gg +
  geom_point(aes(y=value + 2*sign(value)), data = ~ subset(., star), pch = 8) +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image: same ggplot with stars and relocated legend]

Comment: Thanks so much! I do not think there's a mirrored plot in this configuration here in SO. Actually I am not sure what are the asterisks either, have asked a colleague. I will try grouping concentrations 1-3 for each compound by changing factor order and perhaps plotting an empty bar in between.

Answer (score 1):

Like r2evans stated, the only way to do this is to use negative values in your data, and then manually use `abs()` when labelling. More specifically, it would look something like this:

```
ggplot(long.dat, aes(x=L1, group=volatile, y=value, fill=variable)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", position= "identity") +
scale_y_continuous(breaks= c(-25,-15,-5,5,15,25),labels=abs(c(-25,-15,-5,5,15,25)))
```

Of course, use whatever labels make the most sense for your data, or you can set a sequence of numbers using the `seq()` function.

P.S. I also had trouble with your code, so next time please make sure your example is reproducible- you'll get answers quicker!